# Any way to use presigned URL uploads and enforce tagging?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Is there any way to issue a presigned URL to a client to upload a file to S3, and ensure that the uploaded file has certain tags? Using the Python SDK here as an example, this generates a URL as desired:

```python
s3.generate_presigned_url('put_object', 
                          ExpiresIn=3600,
                          Params=dict(Bucket='foo', 
                                      Key='bar', 
                                      ContentType='text/plain', 
                                      Tagging='foo=bar'))
```

This is satisfactory when uploading while explicitly providing tags:

```bash
$ curl 'https://foo.s3.amazonaws.com/bar?AWSAccessKeyId=...&Signature=...&content-type=text%2Fplain&x-amz-tagging=foo%3Dbar&Expires=1538404508' \
  -X PUT
  -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
  -H 'x-amz-tagging: foo=bar' \
  --data-binary foobar
```

However, S3 also accepts the request when omitting `-H 'x-amz-tagging: foo=bar'`, which uploads the object without tags. Since I don't have control over the client, that's… bad.

I've tried creating an empty object first and tagging it, then issuing the presigned URL to it, but `PUT`ting the object replaces it entirely, including removing any tags.

I've tried issuing a presigned `POST` URL, but that doesn't seem to support the `tagging` parameter at all:

```python
s3.generate_presigned_post('foo', 'bar', {'tagging': '<Tagging><TagSet><Tag><Key>Foo</Key><Value>Bar</Value></Tag></TagSet></Tagging>'})
```

```bash
$ curl https://foo.s3.amazonaws.com/ \
  -F key=bar \
  -F 'tagging=<Tagging><TagSet><Tag><Key>Foo</Key><Value>Bar</Value></Tag></TagSet></Tagging>'
  -F AWSAccessKeyId=... \
  -F policy=... \
  -F signature=... \
  -F file=@/tmp/foo

<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Invalid according to Policy:
Extra input fields: tagging</Message>...
```

I simply want to let a client upload a file directly to S3, and *ensure* that it's tagged a certain way in the process. Any way to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
fields = {
    "tagging": "<Tagging><TagSet><Tag><Key>foo</Key><Value>bar</Value></Tag></TagSet></Tagging>"
    "x-amz-meta-u1": "value1",
    "x-amz-meta-u2": "value2"
}
conditions = [{key: value} for key, value in fields.items()]


presignedurl = s3_client.generate_presigned_post(
    bucket_name, "YOUR_BUCKET_NAME",
    Fields=copy.deepcopy(fields),
    Conditions=copy.deepcopy(conditions)
)
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick! To clarify, I need to use `{'tagging': '...'}` with the verbose XML tag set syntax for both fields and conditions, and that seems to work as required.

Answer (score 1):

Python code:

```
fields = {
    'tagging': '<Tagging><TagSet><Tag><Key>Foo</Key><Value>Bar</Value></Tag></TagSet></Tagging>',
}
conditions = [
    {'tagging': '<Tagging><TagSet><Tag><Key>Foo</Key><Value>Bar</Value></Tag></TagSet></Tagging>'}
]


presigned_url = s3_client.generate_presigned_post(
    Bucket="foo",
    Key="file/key.json",
    Fields=copy.deepcopy(fields),
    Conditions=copy.deepcopy(conditions)
)
```

CURL command:

```
$ curl -v --form-string "tagging=<Tagging><TagSet><Tag><Key>Foo</Key><Value>Bar</Value></Tag></TagSet></Tagging>" \
    -F key=file/key.json \
    -F x-amz-algorithm=... \
    -F x-amz-credential=... \
    -F x-amz-date=... \
    -F x-amz-security-token=... \
    -F policy=...\
    -F x-amz-signature=... \
    -F file=@key.json \
    https://foo.s3.amazonaws.com/
```

#### Explanation

It is imperative that `--form-string` is used in the CURL command, otherwise CURL will interpret the `=<` as reading in a file!

Also ensure that `key.json` is in your current working directory for CURL to upload the file to S3 using the pre-signed-url.