# Using presigned to upload a file to "Glacier Instant Retrieval" with tags

Tags: amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I'm using the following code:

```
import boto3
import requests

s3_client = boto3.client(
    "s3",
    region_name=AWS_REGION,
    aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
)

url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(
    "put_object",
    Params=dict(
        Bucket=MY_BUCKET,
        Key=key,
        StorageClass="GLACIER_IR",
        Tagging="key1=value1&key2=value2"
    ),
    ExpiresIn=EXPIRATION,
)

with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
    data = file.read()
    response = requests.put(url, data=data)
```

The response is 200, the file is uploaded, but the tags are missing. I tried to do the same with the regular boto3 function (see code below) and it did work, so why the presigned url does not?

```
s3_client.put_object(Bucket=MY_BUCKET, Key=key, Body=file, StorageClass="GLACIER_IR",
                         Tagging="key1=value1&key2=value2")
```

I also tried to change the storage class and got the same problem

Comment: You need to specify the tags during the upload. Additionally see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52593556/any-way-to-use-presigned-url-uploads-and-enforce-tagging to enforce the client actually sends the tags along.

Comment: @luk2302 Thanks, I saw that post and did not find a way to configure the upload to Glacier Instant Retrieval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As luk3202 said, the tags are specified during the upload, so I tried:

```
response = requests.put(url, data=data,
                            headers={"x-amz-tagging": "key1=value1&key2=value2"})
```

and it worked!