# Number of ways you can upload a file mainly trying to offload expensive task from our server

Tags: file, upload, backend

Traditional way:
How it works:
The user uploads the file to the application server.
The application server saves the upload to a temporary space for processing.
The application transfers the file to a database, file server, or object store for persistent storage.

Advantages & Disadvantages:
While the process is simple, it can have significant side effects on the performance of the web server in busier applications. Media uploads are typically large, so transferring these can represent a large share of network I/O and server CPU time. You must also manage the state of the transfer to ensure that the entire object is successfully uploaded, and manage retries and errors.
This is challenging for applications with spiky traffic patterns. For example, in a web application that specializes in sending holiday greetings, it may experience most traffic only around holidays. If thousands of users attempt to upload media around the same time, this requires you to scale out the application server and ensure that there is sufficient network bandwidth available.

2. Sharing creds with client so that it can directly upload the file to s3 using aws’s sdk. But its bad because js can be extracted and creds can be leaked.(very dumb way but at least load not coming to our server)
3. Serverless uploading:
   API-gateway->lambda function(512MB max)->s3
   Advantages & Disadvantages:

Advantages are same as traditional way just load would not come on server.
Time restriction & memory restriction which is configurable but it can be costly if due to traffic because what lambda chargers wrt time it took to execute and tootal memory consumed during execution.

Api Gateway-> s3
Advantages & Disadvantages:

Dont know a lot but auth/api-key can be seen in outgoing network calls and can be copied then our disk and everyone(unauthorized) is using it although we can limit what they can do by changing policies of roles assigned but still have so many loopholes.

4. Offloading the major part to AWS servers our servers will just give the signed URL and finish the upload wrt that s3 will merge all the chunks and put the file in s3.

What we can do is we can have our own server which will generate a pre-signed URL and give that to the client and then the client can upload to s3 using that signed URL and after finishing client again has to hit our own server to send the complete upload to that upload id with all the e-tags received from client.

right now wrote whole code in js can write using any language as log as aws-sdk exists for that language.

I can share my code (because it's not proprietary and I just stitched every small part (which i got from internet by reading docs or different blogs) to get the full solution) if you want full context. Already have done k6 load testing but still

someone to answer and clear my doubts

Answer (score 0):

You should not be sharing any credentials with your client, and uploading via a lambda is literally throwing money away and even though AWS is happy for you to pay they would not recommend it because it's a ripoff for no reason.

The presigned url approach is the safest. The url is one-off and provides access to nothing but the upload.
When creating the presigned url attach some tags to the object like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52593556/any-way-to-use-presigned-url-uploads-and-enforce-tagging).

You can then attach listeners to s3 to process files when they are uploaded. Object tags and/or location help you at this stage to map the uploaded file to the original request.

If you expect a very high concurrent load you can queue the requests at the signed url creation stage.